# Chrome extension doesn't show popup after packing

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auth0

I am making a Chrome Extension with Login functionality from Auth0, to do that, if user clicks on a login button, it shows login page from Auth0.

On my local machine, I am using local folder to `load unpacked extension`, then when I click login button, it shows login popup page.

But When I click `pack extension`, it stops showing Popup page.

My Manifest includes:

`"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "identity",
    "notifications"
]`

`"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "***.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": ["profile"]
  }`

I checked on background page library JS files for auth0 is also loading.

What else can be problem here?

Comment: Did you "Uninstall the unpacked version of the Chrome app so it won't conflict with the packed app."? From Step 3 here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278?hl=en

Comment: yeah, I am everytime uninstalling and installing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with `Allowed Callback URLs` on auth0 settings and Chrome Extension ID.

On Auth0 setting, my callback URL is https://some-id-for-my-extesion.chromiumapp.org/auth0, this ID is same if developer chooses source code folder because I included export key in my `manifest.json`.

However, when I pack my extension, it gives me different ID for extension even I don't specify key, and `manifest.json` still includes export key.So after packing my ID would be `packed-ext-id`, so my callback URL also should be `http://packed-ext-id.chromiumapp.org/auth0`

If you come up with this problem, please check callback URLs on auth0, and make sure it matches with extension.

You can see ID below your extension.

[image: ID example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937727/implement-auth0-into-chrome-extension-with-one-time-use-tokens?noredirect=1#comment90845062_51937727    heeelp!!!