# implement Auth0 into chrome extension with one time use tokens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I'm making a chrome extension where I want to create a security method for my chrome extension to stop it from getting shared without me in the process

I have an idea to generate a token somewhere (usually some backend, maybe server of the website that gets user registrations/payments my website which I am building with worpress), send token via email, get email+token in extension, make a request to the webserver to verify that they're valid. This seems like a typical auth flow except the password is now the token, which is generated instead of the set by the user. In other news, I have more ideas (Extension-side prng with shared seed, can check to see if the token is within X generations for eg.)

I want to be able to sell tokens on my website which only allow one user to prevent the token from being shared.

I tried to setup the Auth0 for the chrome extension but I keep getting errors and the process doesn't lead to how I would want to be done.

[youtu.be/D0M1wid1L3Q?t=353](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0M1wid1L3Q&feature=youtu.be&t=353)

[youtu.be/D0M1wid1L3Q?t=418](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0M1wid1L3Q&feature=youtu.be&t=418)

is a great example of what I want to be able to do. Can anyone help me doing this? I am building my website in wordpress not hard coding it so I'm not sure on How to do this exactly

If anyone can point me in a direction of what I am supposed to do or maybe provide some code that could help me?

I tried to

```
npm install auth
```

and put that in my `manifest.json` bit it doesn't work and it seems as if it doesn't do what I want.

I have found this url which might get me heading in the right direction:

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @noogui I dont know where to start?

Comment: I went to auth0.com and followed the instructions on there chrome extension install but It doesn't do what I want they add in there own login with a password  @noogui

Comment: here is the chrome extension security method that I want to mimic   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copbot/immelbeiihmmjebckopecegbndefenjf/related

Comment: how do you want users to authenticate? Will they sign in using their gmail account? A new username/password combo? You said you tried Auth0 but said "add own login with password" - What do you mean by this? Is it you want folks to sign up and they receive an email that let's them access the chrome extension functionality (otherwise it is hidden until you receive access through email)? Also, you can try sharing your use case over in community.auth0.com you might have better luck or find a similar scenario in the forum.

Comment: @kimcodes  I want them to sign up on my website with their email then I email them a one time use token and to sign into the chrome extension they have to type in the email they received the token with and the token they recieved in the email they recieved after they signed up on my website

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question but what is the hard part? They have an API and you can make a call to the API from your extension script (any) and authenticate users?

Comment: consider using chrome.identity to lock the extension to one account.